# Magento access with key elements

Tags: php, magento

I need some Magento experts to put there valuable time and efforts on this.

I want to print categories name using incremental key element we  named as $i;

why this isnt working in magento,

when we can print `$_category[$i]["price"]` in  php normally.

`<?php  echo $_category[$i]->getName() ?>`

its not working.
i appreciate quik response .
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your `$_category` var is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` you can get the name like this:

```
$_category->getName();
```

And for this:

> when we can print $_category[$i]["price"] in mvc php normally.

I think you are wrong. There is no "mvc php normally". It depends on how each application is built.

Comment: bro i can get name but i want to access using location eg $i=1,2,...
nd fr mvc was just example dnt bother that..
or can say m trying to run echo $_category->getName()->load($i);